# Is my chrome extension idea a content script or background script?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, content-script

I'm looking to create a chrome extension that will mute/unmute certain tabs after a action is executed (like opening a new tab that autoplays audio). This would be my first chrome extension, so I'm curious as to if this would be a background script of a content script, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with playing sounds in different tabs with chrome extensions, and it does require background scripts for the sounds.

Answer (score 0):

To use most of APIs in `chrome` namespace you need a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

- To mute a tab use [chrome.tabs.update](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update).
- To detect a change in the tab's audible/muted state use [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) listener.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, change, tab) => {
  const { audible, mutedInfo } = change;
  if (audible || mutedInfo && !mutedInfo.muted) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {muted: true});
  }
});
```